# Agrupar resultados da query Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Tenho a tabela normal com a *query*.

```
status    |curso |matricula|
--------- |------|---------|
Completo  |Inglês|001      |          
Cursando  |Mat   |002      |          
Reprovado |Esp   |003      |         
Completo  |Inglês|004      |
Cursando  |Esp   |007      |
Aguardando|Esp   |008      |
```

a *query*:

```
SELECT  
    m.statusmat.descricao      AS status,
    m.cursos.nome              AS curso, 
    m.alunos.mat               AS matricula       
FROM p.pessoas
JOIN m.alunos     ON m.alunos.pessoa = p.pessoas.codigo
JOIN m.matriculas ON m.matriculas.aluno = m.alunos.codigo
AND m.matriculas.codigo =
  (SELECT codigo1
   FROM m.sp_matri125(m.alunos.codigo))
JOIN m.turmas              ON m.turmas.codigo = m.matriculas.turma
JOIN m.periodosletivos     ON m.periodosletivos.codigo = m.turmas.periodlet
JOIN m.cursos              ON m.cursos.codigo = m.turmas.curso
JOIN m.statusmat           ON m.statusmat.codigo = m.matriculas.status
LEFT JOIN pqs.linhaspesquisa ON pqs.linhaspesquisa.codigo = m.matriculas.linhapesquisa
```

Resultado que eu queria

```
Completo |Cursando |Aguardando|Reprovado| 
---------|---------|----------|-------- |
2        |2        |1         |1        |
```

Comment: Use o CASE para "pivotear" as colunas http://profmarcello.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/pivot-table-no-postgresql.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477231/correct-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-postgresql-using-case-when

Comment: Motta vi o exemplo que você passou, consegui aqui

Comment: Poderia colocar em uma resposta o procedimento de como resolveu o problema, isso pode ajudar várias pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa usar `case`. É mais fácil contar os não nulos:

```
select
    count(m.statusmat.descricao = 'Completo' or null) as "Completo",
    count(m.statusmat.descricao = 'Cursando' or null) as "Cursando",
    count(m.statusmat.descricao = 'Reprovado' or null) as "Reprovado",
    count(m.statusmat.descricao = 'Aguardando' or null) as "Aguardando"
```

`true or null` é `true`. `false or null` é `null`. Como o `count` conta qualquer não nulo então ele só vai contar os verdadeiros.

Comment: Não conhecia esta síntaxe !

Comment: Também não conhecia

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma usando um `case` e um `count`, como no exemplo que o Motta passou. Olha:

```
select
     count(case m.statusmat.descricao when 'Completo' 
           then m.statusmat.descricao) as Completo
```

Comment: Se a resposta está certa, maraca ela como correta para poder ajudar outras pessoas.